# Abrir um arquivo excel quando abrir uma activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Quero colocar um arquivo ***Excel*** no meu projeto Android. Quero deixar ele já no projeto igual como se carrega uma imagem, e quando eu chamar uma *activity*, quero abrir esse arquivo ***Excel***.

Tem como fazer isso, ou eu to viajando muito? Quero fazer isso pra não ter que tirar print do arquivo em Excel e fazer várias imagens.
Já encontrei uns tópicos sobre carregar arquivo Excel, mas eu quero saber como eu jogo ele no meu projeto já fixo, pois quando jogo o arquivo `.xlsx` ele nem reconhece o arquivo, e não consigo passar o caminho dele para abrir, não sei se coloquei na pasta errada.

Estou usando o android Studio.

Obrigado.

Att,

Comment: Bom, seria um trabalho fazer a leitura de toda a planilha do excel e organizar ela numa tela, para isso tem os aplicativos espeficicos, e quando é necessário abrir algum tipo especifico de arquivo, vc simplimente faz a chamada Intent pro sistema, e ele seleciona o aplicativo apropriado para abrir o arquivo. Mas se vc opta por carregar as informações no proprio aplicativo vc deve adicionar arquivos adicionar na pasta Assets, e na activity usar o metodo getAssets(), ele vai te dar o diretorio, ai é so procurar pelo nome do arquivo que vc adicionou lá e fazer a leitura dele

Comment: Weselly, você poderia me adicionar no skype, pra me dar uma ajuda? Skype: alexssouza3

Answer (score -2):

Acho complicado fazer assim. Pelo fato de as alterações efetivarem pela busca do caminho e uso de uma variável temporária. Já tentei fazer assim e o resultado mostrou inconsistência.

Hoje em dia faço assim

- Faz sua planilha no Google(faz no Google docs) faz o compartilhamento com poderes total e pega o link
  dela
- Faz o seu projeto e no botão que chama a planilha coloca assim:

  ```
  Intent intent = Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Poe o link aqui");
  startActivity(intent);
  ```

Constrói e instala em todos dispositivos que quiser
Não esquecer de colocar permissão de internet no manifesto
Instala o app planilha do Google no dispositivo
Ai vc pode criar várias planilhas e colocar cada uma em um botão
Na prática vc esta na planilha com interface do app
A desvantagem é que todos vão ter acesso total a planilha ai vc tem que proteger os campos com os resultados

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).